# Different method for solving Legendre differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

Here is the Legendre differential equation:

$$ (1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-2x\frac{dy}{dx}+l(l+1)y=0$$

It's well known that it can be solved using power series method but I wonder if there is another approach for solving that. I searched on the Internet and only found following link: [How to solve Legendre's differential equation without power series assumption?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3309599/how-to-solve-legendres-differential-equation-without-power-series-assumption)

but that answer isn't really satisfactory. If we let $l = 1$, finding two linearly independent isn't difficult: [Find two linearly independent solutions of a Legendre equation about $x=0.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346090/find-two-linearly-independent-solutions-of-a-legendre-equation-about-x-0)

Comment: You could try symmetry/lie group methods. The usual reference texts are hydon or bluman. The big boy reference is olver.

Comment: @TSF I'm not familiar with that. Could you provide a link for solution using symmetry/lie group methods please?